# Show cart item discount amount When a coupon is applied in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I would like to show the amount of discount that's applied to each cart item in WooCommerce. I looked at the WooCommerce class/function pages and can't seem to find a matching one. The only thing they seem to provide is the total discount on the cart, which I'm currently using like this:

```php
$OrderSummarySubtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal(); // -> 600

$CartTotalDiscount = WC()->cart->get_cart_discount_total(); // -> 60

$CartTotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total(); // -> 540
```

So how are the 60 calculated? (ie. how are they allocated to each product)

I guess I could manually calculate the discount, but that's tedious and prone to rounding errors etc., don't want to create any confusion.

Surprised WooCommerce wouldn't provide that functionality ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality exists if you look to cart item data.

To display the discounted amount applied to each cart item (individual product price) in cart page, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cart_item_discount_amount_suffix', 100, 2 ); 
function cart_item_discount_amount_suffix( $item_price_html, $cart_item ) { 
    if( count( WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() ) > 0 ) {
        $item_subtotal = $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
        $item_total    = $cart_item['line_total'];

        if ( $cart_item['data']->is_taxable() &&  WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $item_subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];
            $item_total    += $cart_item['line_tax'];
        }
        $item_price = $item_subtotal / $cart_item['quantity'];
        $item_price_discounted = $item_total / $cart_item['quantity'];
        $item_price_html .= sprintf( ' <span class="discount-amount">(-&nbsp;%s)</span>', wc_price($item_price - $item_price_discounted) );
    }
    return $item_price_html;
}
```

To display the discounted amount applied to each cart item **subtotal**, in cart page **and in checkout page**, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'cart_item_subtotal_discount_amount_suffix', 100, 2 ); 
function cart_item_subtotal_discount_amount_suffix( $item_subtotal_html, $cart_item ) { 
    if( count( WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons() ) > 0 ) {
        $item_subtotal = $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
        $item_total    = $cart_item['line_total'];

        if ( $cart_item['data']->is_taxable() &&  WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $item_subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];
            $item_total    += $cart_item['line_tax'];
        }
        $item_subtotal_html .= sprintf( ' <span class="discount-amount">(-&nbsp;%s)</span>', wc_price($item_subtotal - $item_total) );
    }
    return $item_subtotal_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: ahhh, didn't think it would be `line` that does what I want, awesome, exactly what I needed.